# Multiple Media Queries doesnt work. i dont understand

Tags: css, media-queries

Quite simply, for as long as ive been using media queries, ive had a problem where when trying to combine them like so(below)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) and (max-height:400px) {
    /* code here */
}
```

it NEVER works, i always have to seperate them like so

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* code here */
}
```

then

```
@media screen and (max-height: 600px) {
    /* code here */
}
```

As an example, here is some code to show what i mean.

the first link is with the media queries combined.(doesnt work)

http://somdow.com/4testing/b/

and this second link is with them separated.(works)

http://somdow.com/4testing/b/index2.html

Not a huge deal but after a while, it does bloat the code somewhat plus, it should work which leaves me stumped.

Any ideas as to why?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Did you try validating first?  http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsomdow.com%2F4testing%2Fb%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Answer (score 3):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) and (max-height:400px) {
  /* code 1 */
}
```

works very well, but only happens if the width is less than 600px and the height is less 400px (the two conditions have to match):

- 800x300 : doesn't apply
- 500x500 : doesn't apply
- 400x300 : apply

What you want is an OR condition (not an AND) and you can acheive this like that:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px), screen and (max-height: 400px) {
    /* code 1 */
}
```

- 800x300 : apply
- 500x500 : apply
- 400x300 : apply